# Tomando erro na criação de um Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

Eu criei minha API com TDD, mas quando fiz a implementação de um novo metodo no meu controller parou de funcionar os teste.

Eu criei diversos teste que passaram a parar de funcionar quando criei o loansByBook no BookController, estou tomando o seguinte erro:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.wferreiracosta.liowl.api.resource.BookController required a bean of type 'com.wferreiracosta.liowl.service.LoanService' that could not be found.
2

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.wferreiracosta.liowl.service.LoanService' in your configuration.
```

Link do repositorio: https://github.com/wferreiracosta/liowl-api

```
package com.wferreiracosta.liowl.service;

import java.util.Optional;
 
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.api.dto.LoanFilterDTO;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.model.entity.Book;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.model.entity.Loan;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

public interface LoanService {

    Loan save(Loan loan);

    Optional<Loan> getById(Long id);

    Loan update(Loan loan);

    Page<Loan> find(LoanFilterDTO loanFilterDTO, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Loan> getLoansByBook(Book book, Pageable pageable);

}
```

---

```
package com.wferreiracosta.liowl.api.resource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.api.dto.BookDTO;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.api.dto.LoanDTO;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.model.entity.Book;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.model.entity.Loan;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.service.BookService;
import com.wferreiracosta.liowl.service.LoanService;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookController {
    
    private final BookService service;
    private final LoanService loanService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public BookDTO create( @RequestBody @Valid BookDTO bookDTO ){
        Book entity = this.modelMapper.map(bookDTO, Book.class);
        Book savedBook = this.service.save(entity);
        BookDTO savedBookDTO = this.modelMapper.map(savedBook, BookDTO.class);
        return savedBookDTO;
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public BookDTO get(@PathVariable Long id){
        return this.service
            .getById(id)
            .map( book -> modelMapper.map(book, BookDTO.class) )
            .orElseThrow( () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id){
        Book book = this.service
            .getById(id)
            .orElseThrow( () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        this.service.delete(book);
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public BookDTO update(@PathVariable Long id, BookDTO bookDTO){
        return this.service
            .getById(id)
            .map( book -> {
                book.setAuthor(bookDTO.getAuthor());
                book.setTitle(bookDTO.getTitle());
                Book updateBook = this.service.update(book);
                return modelMapper.map(updateBook, BookDTO.class);
            })
            .orElseThrow( () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Page<BookDTO> find(BookDTO bookDTO, Pageable pageRequest){
        Book filter = this.modelMapper.map(bookDTO, Book.class);
        Page<Book> result = this.service.find(filter, pageRequest);
        List<BookDTO> list = result.getContent()
            .stream()
            .map(entity -> modelMapper.map(entity, BookDTO.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new PageImpl<BookDTO>(list, pageRequest, result.getTotalElements());
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}/loans")
    public Page<LoanDTO> loansByBook(@PathVariable Long id, Pageable pageable){
        Book book = this.service.getById(id)
            .orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            );
        Page<Loan> result = this.loanService.getLoansByBook(book, pageable);
        List<LoanDTO> list = result.getContent()
            .stream()
            .map(loan -> {
                Book loanBook = loan.getBook();
                BookDTO bookDTO = this.modelMapper.map(loanBook, BookDTO.class);
                LoanDTO loanDTO = this.modelMapper.map(loan, LoanDTO.class);
                loanDTO.setBook(bookDTO);
                return loanDTO;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new PageImpl<LoanDTO>(list, pageable, result.getTotalElements());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, na minha classe de teste unitario para o controller BookController eu não estava colocando a anotação @MockBean na classe LoanService